# Why blocked pointer events are fired while timed-out function with no delay is running?

Tags: javascript

Why after clicking the **load** button, both buttons **load** and **dummy** covered by the loader's overlay still register clicks?

Sometimes when clicking the **load** button, the loader is not even displayed.

Buttons correctly don't register clicks

- if we for example display the loader from the start by commenting the line 5 `loader.hide();`
- add some timeout delay (*but I don't want that*)

Example (best to run in Full Page mode):

```js
const iterations = 1e3;
const multiplier = 1e9;

const loader = $('.css-loader-fullscreen');
const dummyBtn = $('#dummy');
const loadBtn = $('#load');

loader.hide();

dummyBtn.on('click', () => console.log('dummy clicked'));
loadBtn.on('click', jsHeavyTask);

function calculatePrimes(iterations, multiplier) {
  var primes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var candidate = i * (multiplier * Math.random());
    var isPrime = true;
    for (var c = 2; c <= Math.sqrt(candidate); ++c) {
      if (candidate % c === 0) {
          // not prime
          isPrime = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
      primes.push(candidate);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}

function jsHeavyTask(){
  console.log('heavy function started');
  
  loader.show();
  setTimeout(() => {
  
    const start = performance.now();
    calculatePrimes(iterations, multiplier);
    const end = performance.now();
    loader.hide();
    
    console.log('heavy function ended in '+ (end - start).toFixed() +' ms');
  });
}
```

```css
input {width: 150px}
.css-loader-background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen .css-loader-background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.css-loader-animation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: purple;
  border-bottom-color: purple;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  animation: spinner 0.8s ease infinite;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-loader-fullscreen">
    <div class="css-loader-background">
        <div class="css-loader-animation"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="load" type="button" value="load">
<input id="dummy" type="button" value="dummy">
```

Run times of `jsHeavyTask()` are different on every machine. For me it's around 5s. You can change `iterations` and `multiplier` constants to modify the run time.

*There is lot more of weird I observed related to this no delay timed-out calc-heavy function, especially in Webkit, but first I am curious about this one.*

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: The behavior described is inconsistent with the observations in the example

Answer (score 0):

as first I would try to call the heavy function differently:

```
loadBtn.on('click', () => {
  loader.show();  
  jsHeavyTask
});
```

If that doesn't do the trick, I would try different approach with the show/hide method and use opacity with ponter-events combination for better performance and disabling passing through the clicks.

JavaScript

```
const loader = $('.css-loader-fullscreen');
const dummyBtn = $('#dummy');
const loadBtn = $('#load');
const content = $('#content');

const cssHidden = 'css-hidden';
const cssLoading = 'css-loading';

loader.addClass(cssHidden);

dummyBtn.on('click', () => console.log('dummy clicked'));
loadBtn.on('click', () => {
  content.addClass(cssLoading);
  loader.removeClass(cssHidden);

  jsHeavyTask
});

function jsHeavyTask(){
  console.log('heavy function started');

  setTimeout(() => {

    for ( var i = 0; i < 2e7; i++){
      Math.sqrt(Date.now());
    }

    loader.addClass(cssHidden);
    content.removeClass(cssLoading);

    console.log('heavy function ended');
  });
}
```

CSS (only changes)

```
.css-loader-fullscreen {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 99.99999;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.css-hidden {
  opacity: 0.000001;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.css-loading {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="css-loader-fullscreen">
    <div class="css-loader-background">
        <div class="css-loader-animation"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <input id="load" type="button" value="load">
  <input id="dummy" type="button" value="dummy">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP didn't ask the best way to do something, the question was _Why after clicking the load button, both buttons covered by the loader's overlay still register clicks?_

Comment: @weegee yeah, you are right... well you answered the theoretical question, I jumped to a solution...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this solution doesn't work. When I add brackets to `jsHeavyTask` call, the loader is not displayed at all. Please see my comments in @weegee's answer, and also my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes when clicking the load button, the loader is not even displayed.

Obviously because of this `setTimeout` function

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2e7; i++) {
    Math.sqrt(Date.now());
  }
  console.log('heavy function ended');
});
```

The [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) makes your code, kind of async, so the inside runs smoothly and with the provided delay. Here, you have almost no delay, it's just a simple timeout that runs instantly, the functions inside as there's little to no delay value.

On the other hand, the for loop has dynamic run times.

```js
var t0 = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 2e7; i++) {
  Math.sqrt(Date.now());
}
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

So sometimes it runs fast enough and that means that your `loader.hide();` runs instantly and hides your overlay and sometimes not so you see the loader.

> Why after clicking the load button, both buttons covered by the loader's overlay still register clicks?

I don't know what you mean there but if you mean that you can click as the overlay displays then no, try debugging by not allowing the loaders to go and then click the other button, you'll notice that the click is not registered.

```js
const loader = $('.css-loader-fullscreen');
const dummyBtn = $('#dummy');
const loadBtn = $('#load');

loader.hide();

dummyBtn.on('click', () => console.log('dummy clicked'));
loadBtn.on('click', jsHeavyTask);

function jsHeavyTask(){
  console.log('heavy function started');
  
  loader.show();
  setTimeout(() => {
  
    for ( var i = 0; i < 2e6; i++){
      Math.sqrt(Date.now());
    }
   // loader.hide();
    
    console.log('heavy function ended');
  });
}
```

```css
input {width: 150px}
.css-loader-background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen .css-loader-background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.css-loader-animation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: purple;
  border-bottom-color: purple;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  animation: spinner 0.8s ease infinite;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-loader-fullscreen">
    <div class="css-loader-background">
        <div class="css-loader-animation"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="load" type="button" value="load">
<input id="dummy" type="button" value="dummy">
```

**NOTE:** Some of your stated behaviors are inconsistent with the given observations in the questions, I suggest you adequately validate them.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But it doesn't answers my question. 

1) You say "_...there's little to no delay value_". `setTimeout()` even without a delay gives a browser an opportunity to recalculate styles and layout and repaint, even without requesting for animation frames (I tried also that), and thanks to that the loader is displayed before the async calc is run.

2) "_...loop has dynamic run times". Okey I updated the example with a better example that browsers can't cache, the problem still persists.

Comment: 3) Of course commenting out `loader.hide();` helps. I am also from the beginning stating 2 examples in the question when buttons don't register clicks. The key is however to prevent clicks only while the calculation is happening in the background.

4) "_Some of your stated behaviors are inconsistent...". Yes, it runs differently on every machine. I even stated that e.g. the loader sometimes doesn't show up.

Comment: @DarkPatrousLinX I cannot find any meaning to your comment and how this does not answers your question. Could you please tell what I missed?

Comment: Try to run the example now please and see the console output. It should display the loader for you when you click on “load” button. While the loader is displayed, click on “dummy” or “load” and investigate console logs.

Comment: What do you mean by investigate? Investigate what? @DarkPatronusLinX

Comment: the first sentence of OP... Why both buttons still register clicks?

Answer (score 0):

It simply seems that the browser is memorizing all the clicks while the JS calculation is running. But those clicks are not applied to the **painted layout existing** before AND during the heavy JS calculation. They are applied to the **repainted layout** which includes changes introduced while the JS calculation was running. So no loader overlay to catch those clicks.

I would expect the clicks to be applied to the original **existing layout**, when the loader overlay is still displayed.

*edit*: adding a correct solution below without a need to add some delay

```js
const iterations = 1e3;
const multiplier = 1e9;

const loader = $('.css-loader-fullscreen');
const dummyBtn = $('#dummy');
const loadBtn = $('#load');

loader.hide();

dummyBtn.on('click', () => console.log('dummy clicked'));
loadBtn.on('click', jsHeavyTask);

function calculatePrimes(iterations, multiplier) {
  var primes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var candidate = i * (multiplier * Math.random());
    var isPrime = true;
    for (var c = 2; c <= Math.sqrt(candidate); ++c) {
      if (candidate % c === 0) {
          // not prime
          isPrime = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
      primes.push(candidate);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}

function renderLayoutAndRun(f){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(f);
  });
};

function jsHeavyTask(){ 
  loader.show();
  renderLayoutAndRun(() => {
  
    console.log('heavy function started');
  
    const start = performance.now();
    calculatePrimes(iterations, multiplier);
    const end = performance.now();
    
    renderLayoutAndRun(() => loader.hide());
    
    console.log('heavy function ended in '+ (end - start).toFixed() +' ms');
  });
}
```

```css
input {width: 150px}
.css-loader-background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-loader-fullscreen .css-loader-background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.css-loader-animation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: purple;
  border-bottom-color: purple;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  animation: spinner 0.8s ease infinite;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-loader-fullscreen">
    <div class="css-loader-background">
        <div class="css-loader-animation"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="load" type="button" value="load">
<input id="dummy" type="button" value="dummy">
```